# Android HTTPS $_POST variables missing on backend server

Tags: android, ssl

I've successfully been using a DefaultHttpClient to communicate with my backend PHP server for some time, and now wish to use a Shared SSL. However when I use my web host's shared ssl url, my Android app doesn't seem to be transmitting the HTTP POST variables. The app is definitely connecting to my backend server because I can read the JSON object being sent back to my app. The backend server just reads the post vars and sends the received POST variable back to the app as a JSON object.

I've tested the SSL url in a simple html form where the action= is my secure url. In this test the backend server receives the post vars as expected.

So what would be causing my DefaultHttpClient to not send the post vars when I use a secure url?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: We need CODE. CODE. CODE.

Comment: @user1168400 : placing the code in the question will get responses faster.. please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will might help you to get a idea about posting:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

} 
}
```

And call another function to post in a class:

```
   public JSONArray getProduct(String id, String type) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(type, id));
    JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(productURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

and lastly post it from your main activity like this:

```
     String test= test.getText().toString();
            String id= id.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction= new UserFunctions();                
            json = userFunction.getProduct(test, id);
```

Comment: The code you have cited is very similar what I'm using, and infact I just copied you JSONObject getJSONFromUrl renamed it, then used it in my app. Even with what you have kindly supplied, the post vars still are not being passed to my backend server. That's whats' so puzzling.

Comment: Just check that in your php file that there have you added the post or get method or not? can you post some code what you have tried?

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than this:

Comment: function echo_post_vars() {
   if(isset($_POST['tag'])) {
 $response = array("tag" => $_POST['tag'], "success" => 1, "error" => 0,  "error_msg" => "");    }
   else {
 $response = array("tag" => 'error', "success" => 0, "error" => 1,  "error_msg" => "post var does not exist");
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
  
}

Comment: without secure url the $_POST['tag'] exists and is passed back to Android with the post var. With secure url, $_POST['tag'] does NOT exist. JSON returned to app: 
{"tag":"update_account","success":1,"error":0,"error_msg":""}

{"tag":"error","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"post var does not exist"}